# Multiple Subqueries in where clause

Tags: mysql

I need two filer data in sub query. This is my sub query one

```
(select  CAST(to_char(date_trunc('day', now()-to_date(max(date_time),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')), 'dd')AS INT) AS monthDiff  FROM  loyalty_scheme L 
JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id IN( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11 )GROUP BY scheme_id) ) )GROUP BY T.unipoint_customer_ref_id )
```

it gives int value as a new column

```
--------
monthDiff
--------
5
---------
370
---------
```

I need to compare this two value with another sub query and get greater than value. This is the other sub query

```
((SELECT  CAST(to_char(date_trunc('day', to_date(demoting_time_period,'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')), 'dd')AS INT)*31 AS demortProd from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11)GROUP BY scheme_id ))
```

It returns this as new column

```
---------------
demortProd 
---------------
31
---------------
```

I need to find greater than 31.

I used where clause as below:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM loyalty_scheme L 
    JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
    JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) WHERE (select  CAST(to_char(date_trunc('day', now()-to_date(max(date_time),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')), 'dd')AS INT) AS monthDiff  FROM  loyalty_scheme L 
    JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
    JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id IN( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11 )GROUP BY scheme_id) ) )GROUP BY T.unipoint_customer_ref_id ) < 
(SELECT  CAST(to_char(date_trunc('day', to_date(demoting_time_period,'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')), 'dd')AS INT) AS demortProd from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11)GROUP BY scheme_id )
```

but it throws an error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Please help me solve this error

Comment: Um, no thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query instead.

Comment: Is that your final code - an on clause does not have a where option. Can you add sample data and expected output as text to your question please.

Comment: yes this is my final code .I need to find all filed witch  monthDiff  grater than demortProd

Comment: for example i need to do this ( select * from tablename where   monthDif  <  demortProd    )                                                                                    
 monthDif -first subQuery                                                               
 demortProd -second subQuery